# Custom condition failure messages in Ada 2012

Tags: ada, predicate, design-by-contract, preconditions, post-conditions

Is there a way to specify a custom error/on failure message for pre- and postconditions, by analogy with `Predicate_Failure` for predicates? I can't seem to be able to find anything in the official documentation. TIA.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use a raise expression (see e.g [here](http://www.ada-auth.org/standards/12rat/html/RCorr-3.html#I1024)) as shown in the example below.

**main.adb**

```
pragma Assertion_Policy (Check);

with Ada.Text_IO;
with Ada.Float_Text_IO;

procedure Main is
   
   package TIO renames Ada.Text_IO;
   package FIO renames Ada.Float_Text_IO;
   
   
   function Reciprocal (X : Float) return Float is (1.0 / X)
     with Pre => (X /= 0.0 or else
                    raise Constraint_Error with "X must not be 0.");
   
begin
   FIO.Put (Reciprocal (2.0));
   TIO.New_Line;
   
   FIO.Put (Reciprocal (0.0));
   TIO.New_Line;   
end Main;
```

**output**

```
$ ./obj/main
 5.00000E-01

raised CONSTRAINT_ERROR : X must not be 0.
[2020-07-03 22:20:25] process exited with status 1, elapsed time: 00.32s
```

Comment: That's perfect, thank you! Somehow missed the obvious here.

Comment: You're welcome. I updated the example slightly: you can also use `or else` instead of an `if` expression.